# NPGSQL connection pool issue

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, edb

we are planning to migrate from EDB PostgreSQL to the community PostgreSQL. So we have started using the NPGSQL library instead EDB library.
we configured the same connection string settings as what we have in EDB connection strings.

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="Host='XXXXX';port=9999;username='XXXX';password='XXXX';Database='dev_xxxx';Timeout=300;**ConnectionLifetime=2;MinPoolSize=5;MaxPoolSize=25;**CommandTimeout=300;" />
<add name="NPGSQLConnectionString" 
connectionString="Host='XXXX';port=9999;username='XXXX';password='XXXX';Database='dev_xxxx';Timeout=300;Connection Idle Lifetime=300;Connection Pruning Interval = 10;**MinPoolSize=5;MaxPoolSize=25;**CommandTimeout=300;**ConnectionLifetime=2;**" />
```

but when I change to use NPGSQL library, we are getting the below issues.

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 25) or Timeout (currently 300 seconds) ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
```

I understand, I have to increase the max pool size, but the same configuration is working in EDB ?

I tried to increase maxpool size to 50, but it makes no difference. so I'm expecting a connection leak, but have no way to test or monitor it.

Npgsql version: 5.0.1.1
PostgreSQL version: 9.5

Comment: Cross-posted on Github: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3829

Comment: Why are migrating to a version that is already obsolete and unsupported?

Comment: @jjanes - sorry,  which is obsolete and unsupported?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 is at EOL

Comment: @jjanes We aren't, we only changed the connection library from EDB to NpgSQL, its the same AppServer, and DB server and connection string stayed the same. We are upgrading to Pg12 as part of the migration.